# payumoney payment gateway integration

Tags: laravel, payu

I want to integrate payumoney with laravel 5.1. I have kept the form in blade . Upon submitting the form I get this error:

> method not found

then I tried to put the whole form for payment gateway (payu) in controller. It is still not working. Actually laravel unable to submit form to this url - test.payu.in.

I also used this:

```
 $request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create('http://localhost/mypro/payu/', 'POST', ['param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2']);
```

not working

Please help me solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to use a package for PayU Money. Here is a link it is pretty easy to use.

[PayU Package](https://github.com/tzsk/payu).

Here you don't have to do anything.
Just register 2 route one for request and one for response.
Then you have to do the following.

```
// Frirst:
return Payment::make($data, function($then) {
  $then->redirectTo('your/response/url');
});

// Second:

$payment = Payment::capture();
// And you have the payment here.
```

It is that simple.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried integrating the package you mentioned, but i don't understand how to register two to route for request and response?? Can you please show me or tell me what I have to do?

Comment: You might want to update the package. see `https://tzsk.github.io/payu` for full documentation.